Animate color mix of yellow and blue to produce green
Very new to Blender, but lovin' it!  I have two objects, yellow and blue, which change transparency with animation.  When the items intersect while moving, I'd like to have the colors mix and produce green. (The objects intersect at frames 82 - 118 of the animation.)  I have separate nodes for the blue and the yellow objects. Will greatly appreciate advise on how to make this happen.  Thanks!

A blue transparent object will only let blue light go through. You won't get any green, no matter what's behind it.

Thanks for this input.  Can I use variables other than blue and yellow transparent objects that I can animate and create a green color when they intersect?

To explain in simple terms (AFAIK) : any blue object/light in Blender will only be one single wavelength. In reality, no lights or objects have this single wavelength, it's always about a range of wavelengths (lasers is a counter example). These ranges overlap between two objects and that overlapping enables behaviors such as subtractive colors as you know it. You can't reproduce that range of wavelength in Blender, you would have to cheat either by setting up a material emulating that, or through compositing.

Quick notes on colors
You can't have what you are asking for with Blender without cheating. Because of how colors are coded in Blender (3 channels for red, green, blue), all lights and colors are defined by a single value (or rather by a 3-tuple). In real life, almost all light is a range of colors that our eyes percieve as a single mean color. For example in the spectrum of the sun, green is the most powerful color yet we percieve it yellow because of other colors in the sun's light.
That's one reason why we can use RGB in digital content : our eyes are so bad and unable to separate light that we can represent almost all colors with only red green and blue.
Workaround
One way you can achieve this, is by using a greener shade of blue. The yellow light being coded as red and green, you'll get some green to pass through. In my example I've set the Color Managment to Standard.

The materials are simply Transparent BSDF
Animate transparency
You can use a Mix node. By setting the color to white, the material becomes fully transparent.

Alternatively, if you have a more complex shader, you can Mix Shader between the 2 shaders. It works the same as the previous Mix node.


Greatly appreciate, Lutzi.  Blender has been a great learning experience for me, and you've added a lot to my knowledge base.  Thanks again!

Making progress with your recommendations! (would send a screenshot, but not sure how to add it to this comment).

Great :) You can edit your initial question and add your progress if you want. No need for "EDIT: ..." just edit your question and add a section "Current progress" or something similar.

You could cheat with an Input > Light Path node that you plug into the factor input of a Mix Shader that mixes the yellow and the green shaders, in my case as the front object is made of glass I use the Is Transmission Ray output of the Light Path:


Thanks very much for the reply!

What proved to be an important factor was to use a lighter shade of blue.
I was able to use the Principled BSDF

By setting the Transmission to 1.0 for a transparent material, one of the main things that really helped was setting the IOR to 1.0.
Here's a screen shot of my nodes and the image in render view.
Much appreciate y'all's input!
